# Shortest subsequence with no interval duplicates

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, array-algorithms

Given an unsorted array of N integers and a function *getNextIndexOf*(int k) that returns the index of the next element whose value is 'k', how would one get at the last element (i.e., index N) with the fewest number of calls to *getNextIndexOf*(int k) ?

*In other words, with what values k<sub>1</sub>, k<sub>2</sub>, ... , k<sub>m</sub> should one call getNextIndexOf(int k) so that the *m<sup>th</sup>* call returns 'N', and *m* is as small as possible?

**Edit: you can assume *getNextIndexOf* can keep track of the last index it returns 
(e.g., like a static local variable in C). The very first call it just returns the index of the first element equal to its argument (int k).

Comment: I don't get the question. Since you don't appear to be passing an index into the function, wouldn't every call of it return the same value? Are there side-effects you haven't described here?

Comment: In addition to what Lasse V. Karlsen has said, I also don't see how k[1]...k[m-1] tell you *anything* about k[m] other than "it ain't it". I can't help thinking we're missing some critical piece of the puzzle here.

Comment: I think he missed out to say that you always remember the current position in the array. the getNextIndexOf(int k) method should also take an integer m, which is the current position of the array. Some possible calls could be: m = 0; m = getNext(m, 5); m = getNext(m, 2); m = getNext(m, 7); finally m is equal to N-1 and that is the stop criterion. The question is how many steps do you need to get there (at minimum!).

Comment: I'm sorry to say so, but even with the edit, the question still makes no sense. If there is (still) no way to tell it where to search from, the best you can hope for is just start calling it until it stops returning a hit.

Comment: Even with the edit, I am sure we're still missing some critical information. For example, is there something that can be said about the N numbers, other than that they're integer and unsorted? Do they come from a restricted range? Are they unique? Anything else we should know?

Comment: Also, what's the meaning of "with no interval duplicates" in the title?

Comment: No interval duplicates means that between any ki and kj in the subsequence, there are no repetitions of the value 'kj' after ki but before kj in the original/base sequence. This means that calling getNextIndexOf(kj) after getNextIndexOf(ki) will get you to the desired kj without stopping at some duplicate of kj that occurs before kj but after ki.

Comment: This problem is unsolvable without knowing your full range of possible values that could be in the array.  If you know that, then there is nothing better that I can see than just randomly selecting a possible value, and seeing whether there are any more of that.  You advance if there are, and remove it from the list of possible values if there aren't.  Eventually you'll be left with no more values and you'll know you are at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution (written in Java!):

```
public static List<Integer> getShortest(int[] array) 
{
   int[] nextChoice = new int[array.length];
   HashMap<Integer,Integer> readable = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

   readable.put(Integer(array[array.length-1]), Integer(array.length-1));
   for(int i = array.length-1; i>=0; i--)
   {
      for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry: readable.entrySet())
      {
         if(entry.getValue().intValue() > nextChoice[i])
            nextChoice[i] = entry.getKey();
      }
      readable.put(Integer(array[i]),i);
   }

   List<Integer> shortestList = new LinkedList<Integer>(array.length);
   for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      shortestList.add(nextChoice[i]);

   return shortestList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the array is completely random and unsorted, there is a priori no reason to choose any particular number. So you cannot prefer a number over the other.

I would try a branch and bound approach. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound).
Branch on the next integer to be selected as k and bound on the amount of steps already taken. Keep all branches on a priority queue and always expand the head of the queue.

This guarantees to find the optimal solution.

**EDIT:**

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
Let A be the set of all integers that occur in the array.
Let Q be the priority queue

foreach integer k in A do
  Add result of getNextIndexOf(k) to Q

while(Q is not empty && end of array not reached)
  q = head(Q)
  Dequeue(q)

  foreach(integer k in A do)
    Add result of getNextIndexOf(k) to Q (using q)
```